# How to set paths property in a project with multiple tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have the following file structure

```
|__ app1/
|   |__ tsconfig.json
|__ utilities/
|   |__ files.ts
|__ base-tsconfig.json
```

In `base-tsconfig.json` I have set the `paths` property as following

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "utils/*": ["utilities/*"]
        }
}
```

and in `tsconfig.json` it looks as follow

```
{
    "extends": "../base-tsconfig",
}
```

That should be enough right?
I am still getting below message though.

> Cannot find module 'utils'

Comment: Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: If you have any other paths in your inner tsconfig they will completely clobber the extended tsconfig, see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14527 (this is annoying as it breaks DRY)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `paths` resolution you've provided (`utils/*`) cannot resolve

```
import utils from `utils`
```

you should use

```json
"paths": {
            "utils": ["utilities"]
        }
```

or if you need also scoped entries or sub-entries, like this:

```
// direct import from the `index.ts` barrel
// covered with `"utils": ["utilities"],`
import utils from `utils`

// import from a scoped entry (sub-entry):
// covered with `"utils/*": ["utilities/*"]`
// it will import it from `utilities/special.ts`
import utilsSpecial from `utils/special`
// or, it will import just `utilsSpecialAdd` exported symbol from the same `utilities/special.ts`
import { utilsSpecialAdd } from `utils/special`
```

you should cover both cases:

```json
"paths": {
            "utils": ["utilities"],
            "utils/*": ["utilities/*"]
        }
```

Comment: Could you give an example of a scoped entry or sub-entry?

Comment: Hi @PaulRazvanBerg, I added, I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 1):

The `"paths"` option can be used to inform the compiler of mappings but it does not perform these path transformations by itself. You can read more about this [in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#additional-module-resolution-flags) and [in this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10866#issuecomment-246789510). Most likely you are using a loader which does not 
allow remapping, such as Node.js's require().

There are packages available to help resolve this problem such as [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) and [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths).

Answer (score 0):

The `paths` property should be set in the individual packages' `tsconfig.json` instead of `base-tsconfig.json`

```
// app1/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../base-tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "utils/*": ["./utilities/*"]
    }
  }
}
```